# Underline active tab

Tags: wpf, vb.net, tabitem

I'd like to underline the active tab with a thick line and make it a teal color.  When the tab is inactive, then the underline should disappear.  What I have so far is an underline under each tab but am not sure how to turn it off/on depending on if it's active or not.

```
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#48637E" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#B4B4B4" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>


            <TabItem>
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel >
                        <TextBlock Text=" FirstTab" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        <TextBlock Text="___________"  Foreground="#00A79D" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </TabItem.Header>
            </TabItem>
```

Thanks

Comment: You probably just want to look at toggling the `TextBlock.TextDecorations` property, instead of adding an extra `TextBlock` for the underline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
<TabControl>
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#48637E" />
                            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextDecorations="Underline"></TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#B4B4B4" />
                            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" ></TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.Resources>
            <TabItem Header="First"></TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Second"></TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Third"></TabItem>
        </TabControl>
```

Comment: Ah, thanks.  That worked well.  I jazzed it up a bit by changing the underline to another color.